# how to add UIImage view inside table cells for iphone

Tags: iphone

i want to add a UIimabeView inside table view cells to disyplay images (5 images on tap)
no is it pissible to show Images in table cells??/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add views to a cell, add them to the `contentView` of the cell:

```
UIImageView *myImageView = ...;
[cell.contentView addSubview:myImageView];
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. You can add it to the cell's contentView in TableView's cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Alternatively, you can create a custom tableview cell if you want to avoid the hassle of adjusting the imageView's positions in the code and you can just set the images for these image view in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: i want to add a scrollImageView or based on tap image will change in UIImage view .. so i can do that in table cells?

Comment: ScrollImageView?? I don't know what you mean by that. But changing the image on tap, yes.. create custom table view cell